# .NET Core how to DI DbContext to AuthrozationFilter

Tags: asp.net-core

like as title

I setting db context on Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionStr));
```

and I want using it on AuthrozationFilter constructor like this

```
    public class AuthrozationFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
      private readonly MyContext _db;

      public AuthrozationFilter(MyContext db)
      {
        this._db = db;
      }
    }
```

but it doesn't work, how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use service location to resolve components from the built-in IoC container by using `RequestServices.GetService`:

```
public class AuthrozationFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
       var dbcontext=  context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();

    }
}
```

Or you can use `ServiceFilter`/`TypeFilter` :

```
public class AuthrozationFilter :  IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;

    public AuthrozationFilter(MyContext db)
    {
        this._db = db;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

And add `[TypeFilter(typeof(AuthrozationFilter))]` on controllers/actions . Please refer to below documents for filters in asp.net core :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1
https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to do it. Under the covers this is wrapping `ServiceFilter`

Use the `AddService` api on `Action<MvcOptions>`

```
serviceCollection.AddControllers(c => c.Filters.AddService<AuthrozationFilter>())
```

Need to register your service with dependency injection

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<AuthrozationFilter>();
```

Then inject via the constructor

```
public class AuthrozationFilter :  IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;

    public AuthrozationFilter(MyContext db)
    {
        this._db = db;
    }
}
```

Adds the filter to all controllers. If you need more targeted, probably use `ServiceFilterAttribute` directly.